# Cannot access srx220 router from browser

Tags: ssh, router, juniper

I can't access my SRX220 Juniper router from any browser. It hangs for a long time and shows a message like

> No data Received

I can access it through cli prompt and can see the logs. All web management configurations are proper but still giving the above error.

Observed in the messages log like

> Failed password for root from IP port 14100 ssh2
>
> May 21 02:13:45  domain.he.frmt.ca sshd[20200]: Disconnecting: Too many password failures for root

Comment: Have you tried https?

Comment: It shows like **The site's security certificate is not trusted!**.  If we click proceed anyway, as usually hanging.

Comment: Because it is self-signed, most likely. Just ignore it, and continue. I think you might be able to access the GUI this time, because you have recieved a proper reply (the certificate).

Comment: No, If we click on proceed anyway, it is still hanging. Previously we were able to access through http.

Comment: Reboot the router from cli prompt fixed the issue.

Comment: Good to know, @vimodhan

Comment: But what might the reason for it. Any DNS cache related issue?@Marius